# How can I adjust Python code to map to column names with different spellings, but same values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I am using pandas module within python  to download an input dataset and read in each column in the csv file. In my python script, I have multiple references that point to  specific  hard coded column name in my dataset1 . I have another dataset called dataset2, that has the same type of data as dataset1, but the column names are different. For example dataset1 has a column named "Apple" and dataset2 has a column named "apples". Both of these columns reference the same data values , however, my script only reads in  and looks for columns named "Apple" all throughout the code. How can I modify my script so I can keep my all of the lines of code that read in all columns named "Apple" , but  make is so "Apple" can also mean and read in any columns named "apples" or any other column name that represent  "Apple" type data. For example, if I look through a new dataset called "dataset3" and I encounter a new column called "redfruit" that represents the same data as "Apple" and  "apples", I can add it one place/function in my code, so that I do not have to change all other lines in my code that just have my initial  "Apple" lookup hard coded.

Here is how I am reading in a data set

```
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_csv(input_name))
```

Here is a sample of my code where I am looking for a column name called "Apple" but when it is looking for "Apple", I also want it to look for other columns such as "apples" and "redfruit" and read those in. The only catch is that I have multiple code blocks similar to this that only reference "Apple", but I don't want to hard code "apples", "redfruit" and any other apple type column names in all those blocks, but maybe just hardcode in one area of code  that can be used as a lookup for whenever "Apples" is referenced in my code. The columns are not in fixed positions, from dataset to dataset.

```
#code block 1
for columns in data.columns:
  if column == 'Apple':
       pass

# code block 2
  data['Apple'] = data['Apple'].apply(str)
```

I thought about trying a dictionary, but not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Are the columns always in the same position? Can’t you rename the columns? How big is your program, that it might be worth using some sort of hackish solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need to multiple values for each key, I would imagine the dict would be something like ```lookup_dict = {   'redfruit':'Apple',   'apple':'Apple',   'apples':'Apple'}``` and then you do your logic based around the outcome of ```lookup_dict[column]```

Comment: _I need multiple values for each key, which is not inherent within a dictionary_? I think there are two incorrect or unclear parts to that statement. You don’t need _multiple values for each key_, and even if you did, it wouldn’t be a problem. I’m not entirely sure what you mean by _is not inherent within a dictionary_, but I want to make sure we’re on the same page here: Dictionaries can contain lists, tuples, other dictionaries, etc. as values. Having _multiple values for each key_ shouldn’t be an issue.